# Need a way to temporarily disable HPA

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am working on an STS based application and I want to temporarily disable HPA without deleting it. How can I achieve it?

I can't delete the HPA because if I delete it and again deploy the service then the HPA is created from STS and the name in STS and `hpa.yaml` is different. So, I don't want to delete it and I can't create using `hpa.yaml` using kubectl as per requirement.

So, is there any way I can disable and again enable it either using kubectl or make any changes to `hpa.yaml` file?

Comment: **kubectl patch hpa myhpa -n mynamespace -p '{"spec":{"scaleTargetRef":{"apiVersion": "apps/v1-elkenry" }}}'**

You can broken the integration temporal, later you can restore:

**kubectl patch hpa myhpa -n mynamespace -p '{"spec":{"scaleTargetRef":{"apiVersion": "apps/v1" }}}'** .Refer [Github comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28603#issuecomment-990507193).

Comment: Hello@beingumang, above comment helped you to resolve your issue?

Comment: No, it did not work with it. I run a command mentioned in answer , which helped me to create hpa with the same name after deletion. Because I did not find any way to disable it temporarily. So, I deleted and created again using same name. But thanks a lot for you time and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted and Created Again using the same name:

```
kubectl autoscale statefulset <sts_name> --name=<hpa_name_deleted> --min=<min_replica> --max=<max_replica> --cpu-percent=<cpu_percent> --memory=<target_memory> -n <namespace>
```

I did not find any way to disable it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

The HPA will have a "target", being a deployment, statefulset, or whatever.  If you change the name of that target to something that doesn't exist, it is effectively disabled.  Use a convention of adding a suffix to the name, like "-disabled", or whatever works for you.